# How to find out why a jar was included by Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

We're using Maven 3 with IntelliJ for our IDE.  After a compile we get a bunch of spring 2.0 stuff being included in the External Libraries.  If I look through Maven Projects dependencies in Intellij I don't see anyone with a dependency on spring 2.0 so I suspect it's something we're depending on which depends on it.

My question is how would I track this down?  I tried doing a `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-aop` and even `-Dincludes=spring` but get no results when ran from the root or a sub module directory that I know is using spring.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the pattern passed to `-Dincludes` is incorrect.

From the documentation of [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html), *the syntax of* `-Dincludes` is defined by `StrictPatternIncludesArtifactFilter`.  From the javadoc of [AbstractStrictPatternArtifactFilter](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/artifact/filter/AbstractStrictPatternArtifactFilter.html) from which this is subclassed,

> The artifact pattern syntax is of the
>   form:
>
> `[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`
>
> Where each pattern segment is optional and supports full and
>   partial * wildcards. An empty pattern
>   segment is treated as an implicit
>   wildcard.
>
> For example, `org.apache.*` would match all artifacts whose group
>   id started with `org.apache.`, and `:::*-SNAPSHOT` would match all snapshot
>   artifacts.

Maybe you should run `mvn dependency:tree` without `-Dincludes` and see if it shows up the *spring 2.0* related dependency.  Alternately, specify the appropriate pattern for `-Dincludes`.

Answer (score 10):

The format you are searching for is wrong. Try this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=:spring*::
```

(Searches for any artifact with a groupId that starts with spring)

Or this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework
```

(Searches for any artifact with artifactId org.springframework)

Comment: I tried with the above command, to understand why a specific jar is included. However, the above maven command is executing and saying the build is a success, but no information about the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use intellij and easy fix it.
Open your pom.xml, right-click (invoke context menu) and choose UML > show dependencies (assumin you have UML plugin enabled). 
Idea will mark all duplicate dependency and you can use ALT+Enter combo to exclude dependencies. 
@see also:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/